# Construct URL Rewriting rule for htaccess for 404 Not Found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I need help with URL Rewriting to serve a default image when the requested file is not found.

I want to write rules for 3 different images URL formats:

(1) http://example.com/imgs/user/123-profile.jpg

(2) http://example.com/imgs/user/123-profile-987.jpg

(3) http://example.com/imgs/user/123-678.jpg

If the (1) and (2) are not found then "http://example.com/imgs/user/default-user.jpg" should be served; and if (3) is not found then "http://example.com/imgs/user/default-post.jpg" should be served.

I tried the following code in ".../imgs/user/.htaccess" file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)imgs/user/([0-9]*)[-profile]([0-9]*).jpg$ /imgs/user/default-user.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)imgs/user/([0-9]*)[-]([0-9]*).jpg$ /imgs/user/default-post.jpg [L]
```

Please also tell me - should I put the code in a .htaccess at "/" (document root) or the current path is more preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't seem right and also `RewriteCond` is needed for both rules.

You can have your code this way:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*?imgs/user/\d+-profile[^.]*\.jpe?g$ /imgs/user/default-user.jpg [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*?imgs/user/\d+-\d+.jpe?g$ /imgs/user/default-post.jpg [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time, but sadly it is not working.